# How to custom override a Joomla component file?

Tags: joomla, overriding

I am trying to override the file

```
components/com_mycomponent/view/events/html.php
```

I have uploaded a new file to

```
mytemplate/html/com_mycomponent/events/html.php
```

But it is not working. The page continues to output without my hacks.

Any idea what the problem is? Is it because it is not in the tmpl folder?

Answer (score 2):

The files that you are overriding are the ones in the tmpl folder, so they should be named accordingly.
I would guess that in 'components/com_mycomponent/view/events/tmpl/' you will have a file, 'default.php'.  If this is the case then, you should rename the file 'components/com_mycomponent/view/events/html.php' to default.php.

Comment: The file i am trying to override is not in the tmpl folder, it's one level up from there. Is it not possible to override files outside the tmpl folder?

Comment: No the over-ride mechanism is for the actual template file.

Comment: is there any tutorial out there on how to overide view files for joomla? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Joomla! Documentation pages:

[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

[Understanding Output Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)